# How to run sudo under su?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sudo

I have this:

```
su $username -c ./script.sh
```

The problem is that within script I have 'sudo' commands and they says me

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

How to do this right?

UPD: I need both sudo and su. What I need to do is run script as USER $username and be able to run certain commands within script as root (for example, pacman -S)

SOLUTION: I've added NOPASSWD option to /etc/sudoers before running script and delete this entry using sed after script finished.

Comment: either fix the script or remove su.

Comment: are those users int the sudoers file?

Comment: Configure your sudoers file to whitelist the commands in question without requiring a password. (The TTY is necessary to safely prompt for a password, but if you aren't prompting for a password...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First set `chmod +x` to your scripts**

try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
su - <your-user> -c /path/to/script.sh
echo "good bye"
```

**UPDATE:**

You should find a way to force bash to use **pseudo-tty**

Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

**If the user is not as sudoers do the following steps:**

This is what you need to do in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# User privilege specification
root        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
newuser    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

you have also ways to do:
you can pipe password if it has password:

```
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S
```

OR

You can run the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn sudo -s <<EOF 
expect "assword for username:" 
send -- "user-password\r" 
expect eof
```

Also you can do that:

```
sudo -kS bash - << EOF
password
whoami
echo "Not a good idea to have a password encoded in plain text"
EOF
```

Comment: I know about groups, visudo and other things :) and yep, my user is in sudoers. I've tried su - $USER -c /path/to/script.sh - this doesn't work neither (the same error). sudo, executed under su -c, just don't see terminal or whatever and cannot be executed, that's pity.

Comment: @@EwanCoder I updated again...does this user any password? what was the result of `su - <your-user> -c /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: I don't mind that user enters his password when script is executing. The problem is not in password, but in sudo itself, it doesn't work under 'su - $user -c' process.

Comment: please do not use `$`. If your user is test. try: `su - test -c /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: The result was the same error sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Ok I try to find an answer

Comment: The same error without $. But I'm using $ because $ewancoder is variable which is set before. Look at postinstall*.sh https://github.com/ewancoder/dotfiles/tree/master/.install

Comment: see these links: [1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-877695/) [2](http://www.unix.com/red-hat/130601-sudo-no-tty-present-no-askpass-program-specified.html) [3](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/196897-error-sudo-no-tty-present-no-askpass-program-specified.html)

Comment: You should find a way to force bash to use pseudo-tty

Comment: He is using --session , should solve it [HERE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-sudo-sorry-you-must-haveattytorun/)

Comment: What was the exact solution?